# NGROK changes url from CUSTOM_URL to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, ngrok

I'm trying to make my wordpress website available for others to see using WampServer and ngrok. But when I expose local server to the Internet with 'ngrok http 80' all that people can access is the WampServer admin panel. When they click my wordpress project they get redirected to localhost/wprdpres directory instead of the custom link provided by ngrok. 
I can also say that it worked perfectly before I installed a new theme. Is there a way this could have any influance on that?

Some screenshots:
[image: People can access only this panel]

[image: Tried to inspect and see what might be the issue]

Comment: Hello,

1/ Check your database > table wp_options > **option_name** = **siteurl** & **home**
update **option_value** => YOUR_URL_NGROK

2/ Check your htaccess

Comment: Thanks, this helped although I used YOUR_URL_NGROK/WORDPRESS to have it working properly. Without it page loaded but without styling for me. :) 
Not sure if my .htcaccess has anything to do with that, but just in case I'm posting mine here: 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Thanks a lot for help! Cheers!